# Failed to read a named property 'href' from 'Location': Blocked a frame with origin "<STRIPE-URL>" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I've been getting this error for a while now, and whilst my app technically works(able to make payments in test mode), the error persists, and I believe it's causing another cors problem.

I recreated the problem in a small react app: here it goes,

App.tsx

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  "key"
);
function App() {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");
  console.log("clirentScre: ", clientSecret);
  useEffect(() => {
    const sendRequest = async () => {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:4242/create-payment-intent",
        {
          body: 2,
        }
      );

      setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);


    };

    sendRequest();
  }, []);

 

  const appearance = {
    theme: "night",
    variables: {
      colorText: "#ffffff",
    },
  };

  const expressCheckoutOptions = {
    buttonType: {
      applePay: "buy",
      googlePay: "buy",
      paypal: "buynow",
    },
  };

 

  const options = {
    clientSecret,
    layout: {
      type: "accordion",
      defaultCollapsed: false,
      radios: true,
      spacedAccordionItems: false,
    },
    appearance,
    expressCheckoutOptions,
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-1/2  relative left-52 top-96">
      {clientSecret && (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
          <CheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

CheckoutForm.tsx

```
export default function CheckoutForm() {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe) {
      return;
    }

    const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
      "payment_intent_client_secret"
    );

    if (!clientSecret) {
      return;
    }

    stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
      switch (paymentIntent.status) {
        case "succeeded":
          setMessage("Payment succeeded!");
          break;
        case "processing":
          setMessage("Your payment is processing.");
          break;
        case "requires_payment_method":
          setMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
          break;
        default:
          setMessage("Something went wrong.");
          break;
      }
    });
  }, [stripe]);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: "http://localhost:5174",
      },
    });

    
    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
      setMessage(error.message);
    } else {
      setMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: "tabs",
  };

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" options={paymentElementOptions} />
      <button disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {isLoading ? <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div> : "Pay now"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
  );
}
```

This looks very neat, and follows the guideline I found on stripe's github, but when I run my program on localhost or deploy it on a server, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this error is thrown from once of the extensions that you installed in your Chrome browser. Can you disable the extensions, or try another browser and see if you still get the same error?